# How to draw a trend line by using gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I was trying to use gnuplot to plot a bunch of data. (data from txt file or csv file) Then, I tried to draw a trendline of those data. However, it doesn't work.

The data was originally from a Microsoft Excel file. I saved them as .txt file and .csv file.
In the txt file, the data is like:

```
0.45    1.1 
0.63    1.5 
0.70    1.8 
0.85    2.1 
0.90    2.3 
1   2.5 
1.05    2.7 
1.12    3 
1.3 3.4 
1.45    3.8 
1.6 4
```

When I tried to plot it by using: 
     plot "data.txt"
Then Gnuplot says:

```
line 12: Bad data on line 1 of file data.txt
```

Does anyone know how do I solve this error?

I think there maybe a format error in the txt file. Then I tried to use .csv file.
In the .csv file. The data is like :

```
0.45?,1.1?
0.63?,1.5?
0.70?,1.8?
0.85?,2.1?
0.90?,2.3?
1?,2.5?
1.05?,2.7?
1.12?,3?
1.3?,3.4?
1.45?,3.8?
1.6?,4?
```

I tried 
    plot "data.csv"
again.
Then Gnuplot only plot 2 points of them.

Another question, I would like to plot a trend line by using following code:

```
  set xlabel "I"
  set ylabel "V"
  set xrange [0:2]
  set yrange [0:5] 
  set format x "%0.2f" 
  set format y '%0.2f'

  plot  'data.txt' using 1:2 title 'the lab' with points
  f(x) = m*x + b;
  fit f(x)  'data.csv' using 1:2 via m,b    
  set terminal png
  set output 'output.png';
```

It failed with data.csv again. Is it any problem in the code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I put your data to a text file, it is plotted normally. Also, you need to move the lines `set terminal` and `set output` to the top. And there is something wrong with all these question signs in your second data block.

Comment: Maybe your data file has a BOM (byte order mark) which isn't handled properly

Comment: @MichaelO. Thank you for your help. I have fixed the txt file, but the trend line doesn't show. Could you please give me some advice about that? thx

Comment: `fit` only computes the optimal values for the selected parameters, but doesn't plot anything. First `fit f(x)  'data.csv' using 1:2 via m,b`, then `plot f(x), 'data.csv' using 1:2`